# Expose Amazon SQS directly to clients or via an Webservice as proxy

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I would like to use Amazon SQS in my application to queue requests from other external systems that don't belong to me.

What is the better way of doing this, directly expose the SQS Queue and the required messageformat OR publish a web service (WCF) that queues the request.

Also I read that SQS is relative slow for a singe access, but am I right that it can handle easyly a lot of concurrent accesses from different clients?

Best
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a matter of preference and depends a bit on your situation.  But my recommendation would be to wrap it with your own web-service.

Building your web-service allows you to do things like validation, throttling, schema versioning etc.  E.g. you can reject invalid messages with immediate synchronous feedback to the sender.  If the external systems are publishing directly to your queue, then invalid messages become your problem not theirs, and if you revise your schema and want to reject old-schema messages then you either have to drop them or set up a separate back-channel to feed back information to the publisher.  That adds unnecessary complexity to your system.  Having a web-service would even let you switch to other queuing technologies later if you need to.

But building your own web-service has downsides too: will your own service be able to handle the same load as the SQS API with the same low latency?  It won't scale infinitely like SQS, so how responsive will you need to be to changes in load?  Have you got the resources to manage a separate service?   And it's more work than just giving a client's AWS account permission to publish to your queue.

If you're happy with the extra work involved, and you want a more future-proof system, IMHO it's worth building the web-service wrapper.